# customize login pages single sign on bluemix

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I am using single sign on service from Bluemix using a cloud directory as the identity source. The login screens and authentication is working fine with the default login page provided by the service. But whenever we are trying to upload our customised login page, and trying to log in by providing correct credentials on our customised login page, we are getting the following error:
[login error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9JD0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The error message doesn't seem to be related to login template. Did you clear browser cache or open a private browser to test it? Also, try to restart your application. If that doesn't clear out the error, try reloading the default template. There is a Design tab at the upper right hand side when you open the SSO service instance from Bluemix Dashboard. Click on the reset button to bring back the default template.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working now. We downloaded the default template again and made very minor changes and it worked.